# Syntax Error - Cant Calculate

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out whats wrong with my code. The code is supposed to calculate the total cost of an item using  cost, quantity and promo code if u have one.  It keeps crashing when I put in unused characters such as `!` . Any help or improvements would be welcome.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim decDisplayTotal As Decimal
    Dim decPrice As Decimal = txtPrice.Text
    Dim intQuantity As Integer = txtQuantity.Text
    Dim strPromoCode As String = txtPromoCode.Text


    decDisplayTotal = decPrice * intQuantity
    lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    If decPrice < 0 Then
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = ("")
        txtPrice.Text = Nothing
        txtQuantity.Text = Nothing
        txtPromoCode.Text = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an appropriate price.", "Invalid Input")
    End If
    If intQuantity < 0 Then
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = ("")
        txtPrice.Text = Nothing
        txtQuantity.Text = Nothing
        txtPromoCode.Text = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an approriate quantity.", "Invalid Input")
    End If
    If strPromoCode = ("132") Then
        MessageBox.Show("You used a limited time, 10% off code! Watch your price drop 10%!", "10% off")
        decDisplayTotal = 0.9 * (decPrice * intQuantity)
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    End If
    If strPromoCode = ("129") Then
        MessageBox.Show("You used a limited time, 20% off code! Watch your price drop 20%!", "20% off")
        decDisplayTotal = 0.8 * (decPrice * intQuantity)
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    End If
    If strPromoCode = ("136") Then
        MessageBox.Show("You used a limited time, 30% off code! Watch your price drop 30%!", "30% off")
        decDisplayTotal = 0.7 * (decPrice * intQuantity)
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    End If
    If strPromoCode = ("264") Then
        MessageBox.Show("You used a limited time, buy 1 get 1 free code, so watch your total cut in half!", "Buy 1 Get 1 Free")
        decDisplayTotal = 0.5 * (decPrice * intQuantity)
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    End If
    If strPromoCode = ("125") Then
        decDisplayTotal = (decPrice * intQuantity)
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal
    End If
    Try
        decPrice = Convert.ToInt16(txtPrice.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an acceptable price.", "Invalid Input")
        txtPrice.Text = Nothing
    End Try
    Try
        intQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(txtQuantity.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an acceptable quanitity.", "Invalid Input")
        txtQuantity.Text = Nothing
    End Try
    Try
        strPromoCode = Convert.ToInt16(txtPromoCode.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblDisplayTotal.Text = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Promo Code.", "Invalid Input")
        txtPromoCode.Text = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub txtPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPrice.TextChanged
    lblDisplayTotal.Text = ("")

End Sub

Private Sub txtQuantity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.TextChanged
    lblDisplayTotal.Text = ("")

End Sub

Private Sub txtPromoCode_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPromoCode.TextChanged
    lblDisplayTotal.Text = ("")

End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. A Syntax error would prevent compiling, but you seem to be suggesting you are getting a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand clearly is that a string is not a number. VB allows this laxity but it bites back in many subtle ways.
I presume that you put the single point in any of your textboxes and then try to use that TEXT as it was a string. Sometime it works sometime not.

The correct approach is to ask the Framework to attempt the conversion and if it fails inform your user of the problem.

So, instead of using the various Convert.ToXXXXx use SomeType.TryParse (I.E. [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
 Dim decPrice As Decimal
 Dim intQuantity As Integer
 Dim strPromoCode As String

 if Not Decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, decPrice) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number for Price")
    ClearInputs()
    return
 End if

 if Not Int32.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, intQuantity) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid number for Quantity")
    ClearInputs()
    return
 End if

 Private Sub ClearInputs()
    lblDisplayTotal.Text = ""
    txtPrice.Text = ""
    txtQuantity.Text = ""
    txtPromoCode.Text = ""
 End Sub
```

Now your typed values are stored in the correct datatype variables and you could proceed with the remainder of your code.....

```
....
decDisplayTotal = decPrice * intQuantity
lblDisplayTotal.Text = "$" & decDisplayTotal.ToString
....
```

An important configuration that you need to set for your projects is `Option Strict On` in your project properties. This configuration will disallow the implicit conversion between strings and numbers and force you to write a more correct code.

And by the way, after the checks on the strPromoCode, you don't need to repeat again the process to convert the strings in the textboxes to the corresponding variables